# Align text to support dynamic content

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

In my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XfESP/8/), the `%` symbol is currently in fixed position. How do I align it so that it floats accordingly if the number changes from one digit to two digit to three digit?

I tried:

```
   .style("float", "left")
```

But it didnt work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Not good, but worked [<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/XfESP/22/):

```
g.append("text")
 .attr(
     "x", 
     parseInt(textElement.attr("x")) + parseInt(textElement[0][0].clientWidth)
 )
```

Unknown User's solution correctly.

Comment: You are perfect. Aligning the text next to it using the `x` attr was a great idea. +1 :)

Comment: @UnknownUser You have a competitor now ;)

Comment: LOL :) I don't have any problem.

Comment: @UnknownUser +1 Thats the spirit :)

Comment: @maximkou: One problem: This solution does not work in Firefox. The `%` is overlapping the value.

Comment: Found an alternate. Instead of creating two text elements. We can use a javascript library named [**`lettering.js`**](http://letteringjs.com/) and could target any word using pseudo property :) like `::lastword`.

Comment: @RahulDesai, it's not that bad, rather than very pretty:) I think there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: It works well in Chrome but not in Firefox. What are we missing here?

Comment: @RahulDesai, now I look the problem.

Comment: What is that `clientWidth` anyways?

Comment: @UnknownUser, `clientWidth` is DOM element's visible for client part width, in Firefox this attribute somehow is 0.

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain what are you doing in that statement? I only get that you taking the `x` value of the textElement and I don't know after that.

Comment: @UnknownUser, I get `textElement` `x` attribute value and sum its with `textElement` width. T.e. textElement.x + textElement.width

Comment: Try if you can help him in [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853456/eliminate-border-radius-in-the-interim-of-the-rectangles)

Comment: @UnknownUser Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882042/background-bar-distorting

Answer (score 2):

You can simply concatenate with the `%` symbol and so it dances accordingly.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XfESP/9/)

Comment: You seem to be a champ at D3 :)

Comment: Lol. No! I'm a beginner too.

Comment: Actually the problem here is that the `value` and `%` symbol have different font sizes, thats why two different `text` elements were created. How do I fix this?